# How do I authorize/register visitors on the site?

Tags: craft4

I use Craft CMS 4. Please tell me, is it possible to authorize users in Craft CMS? In general, the goal is this: I want to show some elements on the site only to authorized users. For example, comments. Is it possible to do this? And if possible, I will be glad to have some minimal instructions))
Important! I am using the free version of the system

Answer (score 4):

The free version of Craft does not currently allow for more than a single admin user. You'll need to upgrade to the paid version for this functionality, where everything you mention is possible.

Here's a knowledge base article all about front end user accounts: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/front-end-user-accounts

Answer (score 2):

Free version isn't enough. After you upgrade to the pro version, you could register as many users as you want. The most simple way to restrict access to a full template would be to add the following twig at the top part of your template:

```
{% requireLogin %}
```

That will prevent any visiter which isn't logged in to view the page.

If you want to restrict some part of your template but still allow other parts t be visible, you could set up different user groups and restrict any part of any template to specific user group with the following code:

```
{% if currentUser.isInGroup('groupHandle') %}
      
     whatever you want to display...

{% endif %}
```